# Сокеты и виртуальная машина

Tags: c, сокет, virtualbox

Необходимо связать компьютер и виртуальную машину на этом компьютере с помощью сокетов и убедиться, что связь установлена. Код написан на С в Visual studio. Компьютер и ВМ работают на windows 10. Сначала запускается cервер, а после него клиент, после чего должно установиться соединение.
Если запускать сервер и клиент на компьютере ( не используя ВМ), то связь благополучно устанавливается, но если запустить сервер на ВМ, а клиент на компьютере, то соединение не происходит и за 15 минут, при этом ошибок нет.
IP адрес (192.168.56.1) находил с помощью ipconfig в командой строке.

---

Cервер:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <inaddr.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_PORT "5000"

using namespace std;
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
SOCKET ClientSocket;
WSADATA wsaData;
int main()
{

    int iResult;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    struct addrinfo* result = NULL, * ptr = NULL, hints;

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    // Resolve the local address and port to be used by the server
    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);

    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }


    // Setup the TCP listening socket
    iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Listen failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }


    ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    // Accept a client socket
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("accept failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }


    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int  iSendResult;
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    // Receive until the peer shuts down the connection
    do {

        iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (iResult > 0) {
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);

            // Echo the buffer back to the sender
            iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, recvbuf, iResult, 0);
            if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(ClientSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }
            printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", iSendResult);
        }
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closing...\n");
        else {
            printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

    } while (iResult > 0);


    // shutdown the send half of the connection since no more data will be sent
    iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }


    // cleanup
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;


}
```

Клиент:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <inaddr.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_PORT "5000"

using namespace std;
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
SOCKET ClientSocket;
WSADATA wsaData;
int main()
{

    int iResult;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    struct addrinfo* result = NULL,
        * ptr = NULL,
        hints;

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }


    // Attempt to connect to the first address returned by
// the call to getaddrinfo
    ptr = result;

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype,
        ptr->ai_protocol);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Connect to server.
    iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    }

    // Should really try the next address returned by getaddrinfo
    // if the connect call failed
    // But for this simple example we just free the resources
    // returned by getaddrinfo and print an error message

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }





    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    const char* sendbuf = "this is a test";
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];

    //int iResult;

    // Send an initial buffer
    iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);

    // shutdown the connection for sending since no more data will be sent
    // the client can still use the ConnectSocket for receiving data
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Receive data until the server closes the connection
    do {
        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (iResult > 0)
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else
            printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    } while (iResult > 0);




    // shutdown the send half of the connection since no more data will be sent
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }


    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: [Открываем порты в брандмауэре Windows 10](https://lumpics.ru/how-open-ports-in-windows-10-firewall/)

Comment: Для начала, нужно сделать виртуальный адаптер сети для виртуальной машины, потом соединить физический адаптер с виртуальным мостом, только после этого получишь доступ к сети виртуальной машины.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Настроил, но теперь практические сразу выдаёт ошибку в программе-клиенте "unable to connect to server" на основном компьютере. Решил пойти дальше и вообще отключил брандмауэр в ВМ, но ошибка сохранилась. Нужно ли что-то менять на компьютере?

Comment: на виртуалке бывает у сетевой NAT со своей сетью, или сетевой мост. Мост имеет адресное пространство такое-же как в реальной машине а в NAT своя закрытая локалка. Покажите/посмотрите какие адреса у вас. Если очень разные, тогда нужно в виртуалке заменить на мост.